# More button in UILabel like in AppStore any app description

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have a description of myObject and i show it in UILabel. I want to add 'More' button to my  `UILabel` if a description is too long. On Github i have found [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) which allows to use hyperlinks. The question is, is there some special features in `UILabel` or `UITextView` to resolve my issue or i have to use `TTTAttributedLabel`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best option is certainly to use `TTTAttributedLabel`.

`UILabel` and `UITextView` are designed simply for showing static text. There is no method for adding tappable elements.

As an alternative, before I leaned of `TTTAttributedLabel` I simply placed a `UIButton` with a custom style over my `UILabel`. The button was invisible but still responded to taps. This works best for static text though, as the button needs to be placed correctly on the interface to cover the correct part of the text.

Comment: hi c.cam108  i have used TTTAttributedLabel and when i set the [label setTruncationTokenString:@"... MORE"]; its not showing on label.What should be the problem?

Comment: @BhavikKama did you manage to get More on your string. I'm struggling to get it. Can you help me?

Comment: Sorry, I have never used `TTTAttribtedLabel` in that way - I would manually truncate the string and create the "MORE" text with a hyperlink that would then allow me to manually change the displayed text.

Answer (score 5):

With `TTTAtributtedLabel` is pretty easy to add a "MORE" text at the end.

You have `truncationTokenString` and `truncationTokenStringAttributes`. Super easy!

Example:

```
[label setTruncationTokenString:@"... MORE"];
```

https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel

Documentation: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/TTTAttributedLabel/1.8.0/Classes/TTTAttributedLabel.html#//api/name/truncationTokenString

In my case I don't need anything more because I just change the `numberOfLines` when the cell is selected to make it grow.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the 3rd library [ExpandableLable](https://github.com/apploft/ExpandableLabel) written by Swift.

Set the custom class of your UILabel to ExpandableLabel and set the desired number of lines and collapsed text:

```
expandableLabel.numberOfLines = 5
expandableLabel.collapsedAttributedLink = NSAttributedString(string: "more")
expandableLabel.ellipsis = NSAttributedString(string: "...")
// update label expand or collapse state
expandableLabel.collapsed = true
```

You may need set a `delegate` to get notified in case the link has been touched.

Comment: Do you have any ideas on see less? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41853362/see-less-in-expandablelabel-ios