# iOS: UILabel with a "Show more" button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have a trunk of text in an UILabel

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum eget tortor porttitor, aliquam magna bibendum...**show more**

When I click on "show more", it should expand

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum eget tortor porttitor, aliquam magna bibendum, venenatis nunc. Aenean commodo nisl vel semper blandit. Vivamus rhoncus, lorem sed mollis tristique, dolor velit molestie ligula, eget semper leo augue eu urna. **show less**

How shall I implemented this?

Comment: where have you been stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try TTTAttributedLabel and truncationTokenString to add show more, for adding show less you can use links from TTTAttributedLabel

Possible duplication of [More button in UILabel like in AppStore any app description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17083617/more-button-in-uilabel-like-in-appstore-any-app-description)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use UITapGestureRecognizer and detect the tap location in the NSAttributedString of a UILabel. [Check out my answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29352519/168594) You don't even need to subclass anything.