# "show more/show less" button for UILabel swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel, uitextview

Im trying to implement "show more/show less" functionality to my UILabel in the tableView cell. I`ve tried searching the solution on the web, but they all seem to be outdated.

The caption text should have 2 lines and if its more than that it will expand to the full text

```
 lazy var captionText: UILabel = {
        let lbl = UILabel()
        lbl.numberOfLines = 2
        lbl.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        return lbl
    }()

func setupUI(viewModel: FeedModel) {

        captionText.text = viewModel.postDescription
}
```

I`d love the final result look like this:

[Expandable UILabel sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVMEE.jpg)

[Expanded UILabel sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG3ni.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS: UILabel with a "Show more" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294851/ios-uilabel-with-a-show-more-button)

Comment: @CSmith unfortunately no, the pod suggested is written in objective-c. I am using swift 5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add "...Read More" to the end of UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32309247/add-read-more-to-the-end-of-uilabel)

Comment: In case you are trying it on a test project, you might want to experiment with [UILabel.showsExpansionTextWhenTruncated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/3750862-showsexpansiontextwhentruncated)

Answer (score 7):

You can try this 3rd party in Swift: https://github.com/apploft/ExpandableLabel

Set your label UILabel to ExpandableLabel and set the desired properties:

```
yourLabel.numberOfLines = 2
yourLabel.collapsed = true
yourLabel.collapsedAttributedLink = NSAttributedString(string: "See more")
yourLabel.ellipsis = NSAttributedString(string: "...")
```

It's has `ExpandableLabelDelegate` in case you want to get notification when the link has been touched.