# "See Less" in ExpandableLabel iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm using the third party library [ExpandableLabel](https://github.com/apploft/ExpandableLabel) to implement a ***see more*** feature. I am looking for swift only solutions that include the text in the label rather than in the button so this works perfectly. After adding the library and changing label type in IB I only need a few lines of code :

```
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: ExpandableLabel!

myLabel = 3
myLabel = true
```

I can't however figure out how to implement "see less" after it has been expanded fully. I added the delegate method :

```
ExpandableLabelDelegate
```

and functions:
    // MARK: ExpandableLabel Delegate

```
func willExpandLabel(_ label: ExpandableLabel) {

}

func didExpandLabel(_ label: ExpandableLabel) {

}

func willCollapseLabel(_ label: ExpandableLabel) {

}

func didCollapseLabel(_ label: ExpandableLabel) {

}

func shouldCollapseLabel(_ label: ExpandableLabel) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

to try and gain control of the process but have still struggled. Has anyone else managed to get this right? If so please can you help me out here...

Comment: You description is not clear, and the code is not complete, could you update more details? and maybe you can checkout the demo (https://github.com/apploft/ExpandableLabel/tree/master/ExpandableLabelDemo) for more details about usage.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is, once the label has expanded create a "see less" button the same as the "see more" one that enables the label to go back to the way it was before clicking the "see more". Basically just reverse the process.

Comment: I think you can create a model that store the collapse state, and in the delegate method you can check the state to change the collapse/expand state of the label. Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my personal experience, I noticed that the `expandedAttributedLink` works only if you set it before the actual label text.

```
infoLabel.setLessLinkWith(lessLink: "less", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: boldItalicFont], position: nil)
infoLabel.text = viewModel.description
infoLabel.collapsedAttributedLink = NSAttributedString(string: "more", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: boldItalicFont]);
infoLabel.ellipsis = NSAttributedString(string: "...")
infoLabel.collapsed = true
```

I was able to identify this behaviour by looking at the setter of the `text` property inside [the source file](https://github.com/apploft/ExpandableLabel/blob/master/Classes/ExpandableLabel.swift).

Comment: Can we set the custom font for label text?

Answer (score 0):

For Show Less Implementation.
Use 2 Properties of expandable label.
yourLabel.collapsed = true
yourLabel.shouldCollapse = true