# How to implement a custom ellipses in a multi-line UILabel?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uilabel

When the text of a UILabel gets truncated there are 3 dots inserted at the end(ellipses) with UILineBreakModeTailTruncation .

Is it possible to change these characters to something more custom like in the app store?

[image: custom ellipses in a multi-line UILabel]

Thanks :)

**EDIT #1:**

**I found the way to do that thanks to @random(comment below) [Decrease the width of the last line in multiline UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113461/decrease-the-width-of-the-last-line-in-multiline-uilabel)**

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113461/decrease-the-width-of-the-last-line-in-multiline-uilabel

Comment: Not a problem :) Glad it helped!