# How do I trim an NSString at line x?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsstring, trim

This should be a somewhat simple question. I'm trying to trim an `NSString` to whatever text falls within 150px max height, and then append "Continue Reading" to the end of that trimmed text.. So say we have the following.

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l
m
```

And we have a font of say, 13... we calculate the total text height and see that it's more than 150px tall at 13px font. My question is, how do I cut the portion of the string that exceeds those 150px?

Comment: See answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113461/decrease-the-width-of-the-last-line-in-multiline-uilabel

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font forWidth:(CGFloat)width lineBreakMode:(NSLineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
```

(on iOS7 better use `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:`)

Keep adding one line to the string `while (size.height<150.0f)`.

**EDIT**: This example could work: (Note: If you do not use ARC, trimmedStr should be autoreleased!)

```
- (NSString*) stringByTrimmingString:(NSString*)str forSize:(CGSize)maxSize withFont:(UIFont*)font
{
    NSMutableString* trimmedStr = [NSMutableString new];
    for (NSString* line in [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]) {

        NSString *testStr = [trimmedStr stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@\n",line];

        CGSize sz = [testStr sizeWithFont:font forWidth:maxSize.width lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        if (sz.height > maxSize.height) {
                return [trimmedStr copy];
        }
        [trimmedStr appendFormat:@"%@\n",line];
    }
    return [trimmedStr copy];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do something really rather stupid (brute force) to get this accomplished in my app.  I manually create new line characters and indents in a UILabel.  To do this I find the first space in the text (to get the end of the first word), check if that is beyond my bounds.  If not I move to the second space and check that.

To do something a little more intelligent for you I would split your string in half then see if that half exceeds your bounds.  If it does then go to 1/4, if not then go to 3/4 and check that.  Then once you find the character that makes you exceed your limit then do a backward search for a space (to find the last word that fits) and truncate your string there.  This may seem like difficult code, but it's just like a binary search algorythm, but through your string.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
-(CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont*)font forWidth:(CGFloat)width lineBreakMode:(NSLineBreakMode)lineBreakMode;
```

because it takes into account all \n characters and calculates correct CGSize.